# URL Rewriting .Net IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My web app url is e.g. http://domainname/Search/SearchPage.aspx?SearchID=1-0-0-2-3. I have rewriten the url as follows



 
The user may see the following url  http://domainname/Search/SearchPage.aspx/1-0-0-2-3/DFDF/FDFDF
My code is only conerned with the SearchID. 
Is there a way that i can ignore anything that comes after /1-0-0-2-3 , since i do not use it anywhere.

Comment: hmm, maybe you still have access to searchId query string after rewriting? I can't understand why you need this type of rewriting as usually you rewrite url that is not exist to existing url to be able to process it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ASP.NET 4 available, you can check out the new Routing API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx